# how get month from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i have a date in string  like this: `var myDateStr='1431451872338.00';`

i want, getMonth() from this format date, i do:`var date = new Date(myDateStr);` but always return invalid date.

and the method getMont() always return NaN, if I put this: `var date = new Date(1431451872338.00);` this return the date correct but with my string not

my var myDateStr get the value from json and is variable, if  someone can help me thank you very much in advance, i hope do understand

Comment: Try `new Date(Number(myDateStr))`

Comment: If the Date is in quotes then it makes since that it would return NaN when you do the function getMont() if getMont() is expecting a number. NaN is not a number

Comment: @JacobFinamore `typeof NaN === "number"` (Yes, Javascript is funny like that)

Comment: FYI - Assuming your format is aligned to what the `Date` constructor expects, the decimals `.00` are meaningless.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yea that would end up being true lol so would `typeof NaN === "123"`

Comment: @JacobFinamore No, it would not. And does not, as you can easily check.

Comment: @IngoBürk Woops meant `"123 is a number"` but yea that makes since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use parseInt and do something like this:

```
var myDateStr = '1431451872338.00';
var myDateInt = parseInt(myDateStr, 10);
var myDate = new Date(myDateInt);
```

Comment: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor expects integer, not float

Comment: [Always specify a radix when using parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. You just need to be sure you're inputing a number, not a string.

```
var number = parseInt("1431451872338.00");
var date = new Date(number); //Tue May 12 2015 12:31:12 GMT-0500 (CDT)
var month = date.getMonth(); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` object cannot be instantiated with a string. You better 1st transform your string into an `Int` and then ask for month:

```
var myDateStr='1431451872338.00';
var date = new Date(parseInt(myDateStr, 10));
alert(date.getMonth());
```

Comment: [Always specify a radix when using parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @IngoBürk that's new, never knew it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing in a date string to the javascript date object, it needs to be in the format "yyyy/mm/dd" or something like "January 10, 2014".  What you're passing is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, which is only accepted by the date object as a number.  You need to change the type of your input variable.

Please make sure to research carefully before answering questions - the answer to your question is clearly stated on many date references like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

One Liner

```
var month = date.getMonth(Date(parseInt("1431451872338.00")));
```